How is the angular momentum of lattice vibrations transferred to the rigid rotation of the sample?
The Einstein-de Haas effect describes that changes in magnetization induce mechanical rotation. In Einstein-de Haas experiment, a cylindrical ferromagnet was wrapped with a wire. When an electric current is injected into the wire, the magnet is observed to rotate. This rotation occurs because the magnetic field induced by the current alters the angular momentum of electrons. In order to conserve the total angular momentum, the magnet acquires an equal and opposite mechanical angular momentum and therefore begins to macroscopically rotate.
Recently, some ultrafast demagnetization experiments have pointed out that electrons can transfer angular momentum to atoms, forming circularly polarized phonons (phonons carrying angular momentum).In this concept, an important question emerges for further exploration: how is the angular momentum of lattice vibrations (phonons) transferred to the macroscopic rotation of the sample? What is the exact physical process involved? Might there be a connection to non-harmonic atomic potentials?
